# laravel 10 polymorphic relationships

Tags: polymorphism, laravel-10

I am switching to Laravel after using "pure" MVC PHP, and have come upon the following issue:
I have a table "words-tbl' containing some 8K words. this table contains words in French, and their "translation(S) in 4 different languages.
For the moment the 'reference language' is only French which makes the relations a 'one-to-many' relation, I guess.
IN 'pure PHP', I had a table (relations with a row for each initial french word_id, and the corresponding word _id of it's translations ,.
For example, if one french word had any word_id of 1, I would have X rows in this table all with the corresponding "1" word_id and foreign_word_id(S) for  for each of it's translations (whatever the language...), plus an few other data related to both words

I am trying to mimick this in Laravel 10, using the one-to-many relationship, using of course the same table to work this relation upon..
Could someone kindly set me on the right track here ...?
Many thanks,
JMB

tried to understand how to..:

- use polymorph relationships in Laravel;
- tried to apply this to a unique table ;